# How to resize image on imagewick in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I want to resize only the images which are greater then a particular size, not smaller one
like

```
 has_attached_file :avatar ,:styles => {:small => "120*120>",:thumb => "50*50>"}
```

By default it should not resize any image of dimenisons less then the mentioned dimensions.
But if a small image of size `32*32` is given then  it is resizing it also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the answer actually in the

> :styles instead of :small => "120*120>" it should be "120x120>"